# How to use local namespace with model_rebuild in Pydantic V2

Tags: python, pydantic, sqlmodel, pydantic-v2

I'm using Pydantic with SQLModel in an app in which I dynamically generate models for different SQLModel metaclass instances (each one linked to a different database).
With Pydantic v1 I was using `update_forward_refs` with a `localns` parameter, but I am unable to find the equivalent in Pydantic v2.
I really need to use `localns` since models are bound to a SQLModel subclass.

My classes were defined like so :

```
def generate_user_model(sqlmodel_class, repository):
    class UserModel(sqlmodel_class, table=True):
        id: Optional[int] = Field(default=None, primary_key=True)
        name: str

    UserModel.__module__ = sqlmodel_class.__name__
    repository['UserModel'] = UserModel
```

And used like so.

```
class DBMetaclass:
    def __init__(self, sqlmodel_class):
        self.sqlmodel_class = sqlmodel_class
        self.repository = {}

    def generate_models():
        generate_user_model(self.sqlmodel_class)
        # other model defs...

        for cls in self.repository.values():
            cls.update_forward_refs(**self.repository)
```

Since some models are referencing each other but are dynamically generated I need to use update_forward_refs on each generate model, using only local namespace corresponding to the current SQLModel subclass.

I would like to migrate to Pydantic V2 but the `model_rebuild` that replaces `update_forward_refs` method does not take `localns` parameter. How should I proceed?